# How to fix docker vulnerabilities (USN-4048-1) in ubuntu 18.08 LTS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have AWS EC2 ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine. I want to fix the docker vulnerabilities (USN-4048-1).

Installed package : docker.io_17.03.2-0ubuntu7~ppa1

Fixed package : docker.io_18.09.7-0ubuntu1~18.04.3

How can i do that ? What's the steps to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to follow below step:

If the update-notifier-common package is installed, Ubuntu will alert you about pending updates via the message of the day (motd) upon console or remote login.

After logging in, you can check for and apply new updates with:

When performing an update, first review what apt is going to do, then confirm that you want to apply the updates (this is particularly true when running the development release).

If you would prefer to have updates applied automatically, make sure the unattended-upgrades package is installed, then run 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades'. Please note that updates may restart services on your server, so this may not be appropriate for all environments.

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

source : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades?_ga=2.36307296.1783287754.1567592268-1506938917.1567592268